# Is it possible to track the progress of a mysql script execution using PHP mysqli_multi_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

The code is the following:

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query)) {

    $token = $_POST['token'];

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO _usuarios (
            login_usuario, 
            nombre_usuario, 
            password_usuario, 
            id_perfil, 
            fecha_creacion_usuario, 
            id_usuarioCreate)
        VALUES (
            '$token',
            '$token',
            '$passCreate',
            6,
            NOW(),
            1
        );";

    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) 
    {
        echo "User created successfully";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error creating user: " . $conn->error.$query;
    }
}
```

Everytime I run the multiquery (which in this case is a very large sql script for a database creation) and I try to execute the INSERT below, I get the same message:

'Table _usuarios doesn't exist'

I believe that it is because the script hasn't finished running by the time I'm trying to do the insert.

Any ideas?

Comment: That error  means you don't have created the table _usuarios on the selected db, maybe you should verify on your connection that your desired db is selected.

Comment: This is the wrong way to use MySQL and PHP. You are open to SQL injections. Use PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
while ($mysqli->next_result());
```

Run this code after your multi query to make PHP script wait until last query gets executed.

Note that for your second query you should be using prepared statements instead of adding variables in query directly.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked quite well!

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the error message, it seems as if your table has not been created yet. You can do the following in order to have it created in one step:

```
    $token = $_POST['token'];
    $token1 = $_POST['token1']; // I do not know it exactly anymore how you can retrieve all the POSTS

    SELECT $token, $token1, field3, field4, ... INTO _usuarios
```

Now your table will be created and filled at the same time.